# Java - how to stop nested loops from checking same indices twice?

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

Given an array and a number N call a pair of numbers from the array a Perfect Pair if their sum is equal to N.

Find all of the perfect pairs and return the sum of their indices. Note that any element of the array can only be counted in one Perfect Pair.

Examples

pairwise([1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5], 7) = 11
Since the Perfect Pairs are (4, 3) and (2, 5) with indices 1 + 3 + 2 + 5 = 11.

pairwise([1, 3, 2, 4], 4) = 1
Since the element at index 0 (i.e. 1) and the element at index 1 (i.e. 3) form the only Perfect Pair.

Input 1 (arr) → array.integer :
array of non-negative integers

Input 2 (N) → integer :
positive integer

Output → integer :
sum of indices and 0 if no Perfect Pair exists

My Code:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x[] = {1,4,2,3,0,5};
        System.out.println(pairwise(x, 7)); 
    }

     public static int pairwise(int[] arr, int N) {    
        int t=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
            if(arr[i]+arr[k] == N){
              t+=i+k;
            } 
          }
        }
        return t;
     }
```

The problem is my code checks indices twice, like (0,1) and (1,0) are treated like different indices.

Comment: Mayby you sould use `Map<Integer, Integer>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest options is to not check these in the first place.  I assume `i == k` is not valid so you don't want to check `k < i` either.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x[] = {1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5};
    System.out.println(pairwise(x, 7));
}

public static int pairwise(int[] arr, int N) {
    int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[k] == N) {
                t += i + k;
                arr[i] = arr[k] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // don't use these again
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

prints

```
11
```

This ensures you won't go over the same numbers twice.

Note: this is an O(n^2) approach, if you have more numbers you will want an O(n) approach which means using a set or map of numbers.

```
// O(n)
Map<Integer, Integer> intToIndex = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    intToIndex.put(arr[i], i);

// O(n)
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int numberToLookFor = N - arr[i];
    Integer k = intToIndex.get(numberToLookFor);
    if (k != null) {
        assert arr[i] + arr[k] == N;
        // do something with i and k
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the array has duplicate numbers [1, 4, 1] and N is 5 for example.

Comment: It skips `(0,0) (1,1)...`. But the OP wants these also

Comment: I Tested this on the test case i provided in my code, the output is 22, while the correct is 11

Comment: It's not clear that a number can be paired with itself.  Since there is a suggestion of avoid duplicates, I would assume `(0, 0)` would be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidMatriguet I have added a change to the first example so that pairs won't be used again.

Comment: @DavidMatriguet it produces `11` for me.

Answer (score 2):

Start the second loop from `i`, not `0`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 for(int j = i; j < 10; j ++)
   {
       System.out.println("(" + i + "," + j + ")");
   }  
}

Output:
I reduced `10` to `4`.
    (0,0)
    (0,1)
    (0,2)
    (0,3)
    (0,4)
    (1,1)
    (1,2)
    (1,3)
    (1,4)
    (2,2)
    (2,3)
    (2,4)
    (3,3)
    (3,4)
    (4,4)
```